# Calling method on a PHP object which contains an array

Tags: php, object

I have a PHP class called "food". The internal data structure of the class is an Array.

```
class Food
{


public $dataArray;// = array();
public $sidesArray;// = array();

public function __construct()
{
    $this->dataArray = array();
    $this->sidesArray = array();

    echo"Created new Food instance<br/>";

}

public function setName($food_Name)
{
    $this->dataArray["food_name"] = $food_Name;
}

public function getName()
{
    return $this->dataArray["food_name"];
}
```

When I call this method of the class :

```
$food_name = $foodItem->getName();
```

I get this exception:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object......
```

However when I call this function on the object:

```
print_r($foodItem);
```

I get this output:

```
Array ( [0] => Food Object ( [dataArray] => Array ( [food_name] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tomato Soup ) [food_Cals] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 200 ) [food_Desc] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => great ) [food_price] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 2.00 ) [num_sides] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 1 ) ) [sidesArray] => Array ( [0] => Side Object ( [dataArray:private] => Array ( [side_name] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => mashed potatoes ) [side_Cals] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [side_Category] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Sides ) [side_desc] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [side_price] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 2.00 ) ) ) ) ) )
```

My question is why is that method getName() not working?
How do I get the "name" out of the foodItem object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone notice that `$dataArray` is `public`?  Was that a typo because you have access to array of the instantiated object if its `public` without needing to call the function `getName()`.

Comment: Its public for now, before deployment this will be changed. Thanks for noticing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `$foodItem` is an array of `Food` objects.

You will need to loop over the array or reference specific items by index to use the class methods, eg

```
// loop
foreach ($foodItem as $food) {
    echo $food->getName();
}

// direct access
echo $foodItem[0]->getName();
```

Be careful as you will trigger an `E_NOTICE` "undefined index" error if attempting to call `Food::getName()` before a name has been set via `Food::setName()`.

I'd be inclined to set the name in the constructor

```
public function __construct($name)
{
    $this->dataArray = array('food_name' => $name);

    // any other constructor tasks
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to try it that way

```
$foodItem[0]->getName();
```

because your object is in $foodItem[0]. Then it will be working. But also a remark:

- if you make a set/get method you should make $dataArray private. If not you can access it directly. That's not a proper oop.

Comment: @zerkms I can only assume Andreas is referring to *encapsulation*

Comment: Thanks Phil, that's exactly what I meant.